# SQL Server - SSIS Upgrading become faster to Sharepoint List Destination

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I have a problem to transfer 800,000 records using SSIS into Sharepoint List Destination.

SSIS is still running, but it takes one day and it can only transfer 20,000 record. So, here we have a time line, that only left 14 days to complete doing this migration from (OLE DB to Sharepoint List destination) for user used the record by this early MAY 2011.

Should anyone assist me on this issues. Thank You.

Comment: Without knowing **a lot more details**, we cannot possibly help. What kind of data structures do you have? How large are those rows? What other system parameters might influence performance? Is this a live system with real-life apps running on it while you do a migration?

Answer (score 0):

its ok, found the solution, its because of the server problem, because we had to application running in the same virtual server. That is, we need to shut off the other application first, then, our migration become faster only 3 days to complete migrate for this 800k record. Before this, we think its gonna finish for one month.

So thanks to our team here, n thx for concern to marc_s & marc_m :)